# Nvidia DGX vs HGX (A100)

Tags: graphics-cards, nvidia

What is the difference Nvidia's [DGX](https://www.nvidia.com/en-in/data-center/dgx-a100/) and [HGX](https://www.nvidia.com/en-in/data-center/hgx/) boxes? (assuming same no. of A100 GPUs and GPU-RAM)

Was unable to precisely find any comparison online. Would be great if someone can elaborate the difference, as well as recommend which one would best suit for which usecases.

Answer (score 1):

this is more of a question you need to ask directly with NVIDIA, either a sales rep of theirs or on an nvidia specific forum.

*This is not a graphics-card, it's enterprise level GPU supercomputing*.

https://hardwaresfera.com/en/noticias/nvidia-presenta-las-maquinas-computacion-dgx-hgx-basadas-las-gpu-nvidia-volta/

> May 2017 : The latest solution presented by NVIDIA is the NVIDIA HGX-1, which has been developed with the cloud in mind and is based on water cooling. Like the DGX-1, it has eight Tesla V100s, but on this machine the price has not been given. Of course, these three solutions are designed for specific computing, servers and special functions, nothing designed for the average user, especially because the price is scary and not a little.

this is pretty good : https://ms-my.facebook.com/DataSciencesCorporation/videos/the-fundamental-difference-between-nvidia-hgx-and-the-dgx-is-that-nvidia-hgx-is-/573138507657930/

Comment: seems DGX is the [original] **standard** from Nvidia somewhat non-customizable, HGX is a customizable solution (like a DGX 2.0) built from hardware that is not all nvidia specific but is certified by nvidia.